# How to search for my questions, unaccepted, with ≥ 1 answer?

Tags: support, search, unaccepted-answer

I wish to find all my own questions that
I have not accepted
and effected least 1 answer. So I input this into the search field:

`user:8712 isaccepted:no answers:1`

[This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1) resulted, but fails the above criteria, because it lists many accepted questions.
So what's the right input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `hasaccepted`, not `isaccepted`:

```
user:8712 hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

[Here's a link.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A8712+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1)

Alternatively, [use the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/300842/questions-with-answers-but-no-accepted-answer?UserId=8712).

Answer (score 6):

This [query string](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A8712%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20answers%3A2%20) will find your posts, that do not have an accepted answer and there are one or more answers.

```
user:8712 hasaccepted:no answers:1
```